# Receiving NULL output for some fields

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm learning SQL from a website. The question they asked was

> Show the provinces that has more patients identified as 'M' than 'F'.
> Must only show full province_name

Table

[image: Table provided]

My attempted answer using subqueries, rather than join (I am trying to learn subqueries rather than the right way which is to use "joins")

```
SELECT 
  (select pn.province_name where pn.province_id=p.province_id) AS Province
FROM 
  patients p,
  province_names pn
group by
  p.province_id
having 
  COUNT(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) > count(case when p.gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

But the output I get is

[image]

When I should actually get

[image]

Why are **NULLS** appearing?

Comment: `SELECT  (select...` is very odd syntax. Also, use modern join syntax. This is a very odd format and not entirely sure it's valid.

Comment: 1) your generating a cartesean product on your join without join critiera.. Not wise why not coorlate the sub query and only have 1 table in your select, the 2nd table would be in the top select as a subquery.  2) your using count when a sum makes more sense to me but I suppose a count of null will still return the proper count...

Comment: If the web site is teaching you to do joins with the "tableA, tableB WHERE" syntax, which has been **obsolete for more than 30 years**, instead of the ansi "tableA JOIN tableB ON" syntax, find a different web site.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a correlated subquery instead?

```
SELECT 
  (select pn.province_name FROM province_Names pn where pn.province_id=p.province_id) AS Province
FROM 
  patients p
group by
  p.province_id
having 
  COUNT(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) > count(case when p.gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

Though I'd prefer

```
SELECT pn.province_name AS Province
FROM 
  patients p
LEFT JOIN province_Names pn 
  on pn.province_id=p.province_id
GROUP BY
  p.province_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(case when p.gender = 'M' then 1 end) > count(case when p.gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

Comment: Just for OP's sake, query #2 in this answer is what your coworkers are going to expect to see. Even if it runs and returns the correct answer I'd be miffed if I was confronted with query #1.

Comment: While I typically agree, in the past I've found mySQL sometimes can be more performant  in query #1.  THis was years ago so they may have changed how the engine operates and it will likely depend on the volume of data in the provence-names table and indexes on boht tables to coorlate.  There are times though I forgo performance if it's a negligable impact in favor of readability/maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps province_names.province.name (TEXT) are NULL, so when you select them using

```
select pn.province_name where pn.province_id=p.province_id
```

You could be returning NULL values from the start.